# TextView overwrites

Tags: android, listview, textview, restrict

I wanted to know how I can solve this problem.

Right now my situattion is like this :
I have a listview with items. An item consists of a title(textview) and a number(textview) fixed on the right(textview with a circle drawable shape as a background.)

But my problem is when my title is too long it overwrites the number.

I wanted to know how can I code my layout that my title will NOT overwrite the other textview at all. So that there would be kind of an imaginary line on the left of the number. And if the title is too long it will go on a next line and not overwrite my number.

I appreciate any help!

Here is my code for an listitem:

**custom_list_item.xml: **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/fach_grid"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAverage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_list_item"
        android:text="@string/average"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout will do, RelativeLayout isn't designed to forbid overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvAverageImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_mark"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAverage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="average"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvAverage"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="fach_grid"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Or you could do a linear layout with a horizontal orientation

Comment: The problem with that one is that my number is even though its alignParentRight = true, my number is right next(in the circle) to the title and the circle is stretched all the way from after the title to the end of the list item

Comment: Still doesn't work number is still right next after the title and background still stretched! But thanks for your tips already!

Comment: is the tvAverage textview supposed to be a set width? It will always stretch if you set the background and let the view resize. You could just use a imageview behind the text view.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: See edit. This would put the imageview behind the textview. Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but it would not stretch the image. You would need to put the width in yourself

Comment: My circle is just a xml file which is a drawable shape or do I misunderstand here something?